# Hide keyboard when scroll UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard, scroll

In my app i want hide keyboard when i start scrolling UITableView. I search about this in internet, and most answer is subclassing UITableView (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499810/tapping-a-uiscrollview-to-hide-the-keyboard).

I made subclass but it's dont work.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MyUITableViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)myUITableViewTouchesBegan;
@end

@interface MyUITableView : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    id<MyUITableViewDelegate> delegate;
}
@end
```

.m file

```
#import "MyUITableView.h"

@implementation MyUITableView

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"delegate scrollView"); //this is dont'work
    [super scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"delegate myUITableViewTouchesBegan"); // work only here
    [delegate myUITableViewTouchesBegan];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

}

- (void)dealloc {
...
```

I use this class like this. But delegate function myUITableViewTouchesBegan don't work in ViewController

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyUITableView.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, MyUITableViewDelegate> {
    MyUITableView *myTableView;
    UISearchBar *searchBar; 
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet MyUITableView *myTableView;
...
```

.m

```
- (void) myUITableViewTouchesBegan{
    NSLog(@"myUITableViewTouchesBegan");
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I have some troubles with this implemenation:
1) myUITableViewTouchesBegan dont work in ViewController
2) NSLog from MyUITableView.m - *NSLog(@"delegate myUITableViewTouchesBegan");*  work only when i touch table. How made it's work also when i start scrolling? 
I try override scrollViewDidScroll but comiler said that MyUITableVIew may be don't respond on this string *[super scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];*

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Not sure why you need to subclass UITableView for this.

In the view controller that contains the plain UITableView, try adding this:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 468):

Here is the cleanest way to achieve this in iOS 7.0 and above:

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

Or to dismiss interactively when touching:

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
```

Or in Swift:

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

To dismiss interactively:

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```

Comment: This attribute can of course also be set in the attribute inspector for those using nibs and storyboards.

Comment: For those who forgets, you still needs to make UITextfield resign first responder.

Comment: I've been doing iOS dev since for 3 years and I didn't know about this until now... unreal.

Answer (score 136):

You can do this right in Interface Builder. Select your `UITableView` and open the Attributes Inspector. In the Scroll View section set the **Keyboard** field to **Dismiss on Drag**.

[image]

Answer (score 43):

Just to add an update to the answers above. The below worked for me in Swift 1.2

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.OnDrag
```

or

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.Interactive
```

Answer (score 11):

**With Swift 5**

To hide the keyboard when scrolling the TableView and stop editing properly, we still need to **combine** two types of answers:

1. Set the keyboard dismiss mode in IB (as **Kyle** explained) or in `ViewDidLoad()` code (as **Pei** explained) for instance:

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

2. Force the current textfield to resign as first responder (as in **Vasily**'s answer). We just need to add the following to our `UITableViewController` class

```
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if !tableView.isDecelerating {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: how will this work if I don't have reference to the actual text field? I have 3 separate views and one view contains table view and the other text view.

Answer (score 1):

**Working solution without writing single line of code in your Controller:**

As your question is to handle the hide keyboard with one condition only (on scroll). 
But here I am recommending one solution to handle textfield and keyboard together which works like charm for UIViewController, UITableView and UIScrollView. The interesting fact is that You do not need to write any single line of code.

Here you go: [TPKeyboardAvoiding - An awesome solution to handle keyboard and scroll](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Answer (score 1):

### Task

Hide keyboard programmatically when scroll UITableView in Swift 3

### Details

xCode 8.2.1, swift 3

### Solution

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if !tableView.isDecelerating {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

### Full Sample

> ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Title"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if !tableView.isDecelerating {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }
}
```

> StoryBoard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="11762" systemVersion="16D32" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="11757"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_4399357" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <searchBar contentMode="redraw" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wU1-dV-ueB">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="375" height="44"/>
                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                            </searchBar>
                            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" keyboardDismissMode="interactive" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="L52-4c-UtT">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="375" height="603"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </tableView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="wU1-dV-ueB" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="L52-4c-UtT" secondAttribute="top" id="0WF-07-qY1"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="wU1-dV-ueB" secondAttribute="trailing" id="3Mj-h0-IvO"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="wU1-dV-ueB" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="L52-4c-UtT" secondAttribute="leading" id="8W5-9j-2Rg"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="wU1-dV-ueB" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="L52-4c-UtT" secondAttribute="trailing" id="crK-dR-UYf"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="wU1-dV-ueB" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" id="mPe-bp-Dxw"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="L52-4c-UtT" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="wfy-db-euE" secondAttribute="top" id="oIo-DI-vLh"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="wU1-dV-ueB" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" id="tVC-UR-PA4"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="searchBar" destination="wU1-dV-ueB" id="xJf-bq-4t9"/>
                        <outlet property="tableView" destination="L52-4c-UtT" id="F0T-yb-h5r"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-79.200000000000003" y="137.18140929535232"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After iOS 7, you can simple use the tableview property

**Swift 3.0+**

```
myTableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.OnDrag
```

**ObjectiveC**

```
myTableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

For earlier versions, implementing the scroll view delegate could work.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        view.endEditing(true)
}
```