# Hide keyboard by touching background of UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield

I was searching some optimized method to hide keyboard on background tap when `UITextFields` are in a `UITableViewCell`. I have made some code Hope this would help you.

Comment: How about this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399357/hide-keyboard-when-scroll-uitableview

Answer (score 1):

I made a category of `tableview` for hiding the keyboard on background tap while `tableview` contains `textfield`.

My header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Utility.h"

@interface UITableView (HitTest)

@end
```

My implementation file:

```
#import "UITableView+HitTest.h"

@implementation UITableView (HitTest)

UITableViewCell *activeCell;

-(UIView*) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSInteger iterations = 0;
    // check to see if the hit is in this table view
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event])
    {
        UITableViewCell* newCell = nil;

        // hit is in this table view, find out 
        // which cell it is in (if any)
        for (UITableViewCell* aCell in self.visibleCells)
        {
            iterations ++;
            if ([aCell pointInside:[self convertPoint:point toView:aCell] withEvent:event])
            {
                newCell = aCell;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!newCell)
        { 
            for (UIView *view in activeCell.subviews)
            {
                iterations++;
                if ([view isFirstResponder])
                {
                    [view resignFirstResponder];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            activeCell = newCell;
        }
        NSLog(@"total Iterations:%d",iterations);
    }

    // return the super's hitTest result
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];   
}    

@end
```

This is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Doing **hittest** doest seem to be the right way

You can implement the touch events on the View on which the tableView resides, like below.

Also assign the textField Object to a member variable in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, so you will be able to resign the particular text field for which the keyborad is shown.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [textFieldObject resignFirstResponder];
}
```