# How to hide keyboard on touch UITableView in iOS Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I am new in iOS development. I want to hide the keyboard when tapping outside of a `TextField`. My `TextField` is in a cell from an `UITableView`.

I have tried to follow some of those links, however without any success--

[Dismiss keyboard on touch anywhere outside UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274119/dismiss-keyboard-on-touch-anywhere-outside-uitextfield)

[Dismiss keyboard by touching background of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321038/dismiss-keyboard-by-touching-background-of-uitableview)

[Hide keyboard when scroll UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399357/hide-keyboard-when-scroll-uitableview)

I am trying to find the simplest way possible.
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dismiss keyboard on touch anywhere outside UITextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274119/dismiss-keyboard-on-touch-anywhere-outside-uitextfield)

Comment: But dont want to write such a long method to follow...

Comment: There are shorter methods as well in that question. It is the same question, I believe.

Comment: There will also help you..

Comment: -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the simplest way to dismiss keyboard

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    [tableView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
- (void)hideKeyboard
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**It's not about touch, only working when scroll**

```
TableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

also have

UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive // the keyboard follows the dragging touch off screen, and may be pulled upward again to cancel the dismiss

Answer (score 0):

you can use Tap gesture to hide keyboard.

```
- (void) tapGesture : (UIGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer {   
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        if([subview isKindOfClass : [UITextField class]] ) {
            UITextField *tf = (UITextField *) subview;
            [tf resignFirstResponder];
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add delegate class `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an UITapGestureRecogniser and assign it to the view, and then call resign first responder on the textfield on it's selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code
Write following code in viewDidLoad and add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in .h file.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                        action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[singleFingerTap setDelegate:self];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

// Listen for keyboard appearances and disappearances

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                         name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                       object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:)
                                         name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                       object:nil];
```

Delegates of keyboard Appearances and disappearances

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *) notif{
 // Do something here
  tblview.tag = 1;
}
- (void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification *) notif{
// Do something here
tblview.tag = 0;
}
```

UITapGestureRecognizer event function for hide keyboard

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
   blview.tag = 0;
  [self.view endEditing:YES];
 }
```

UIGestureRecognizer delegate

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
if(tblview.tag == 1){
    return TRUE;
}
else{
    return FALSE;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the solution in two parts:

To dismiss keyboard on tableview/collectionview tap:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView= NO;
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

(Don't forget `cancelsTouchesInView` set to `NO` to get touch event of tableview/collection view)

To dismiss keyboard on scroll (as tableview/collectionview are subclass of UIScrollView):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
     [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you..

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
 [self.view endEditing:YES]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to alloc a tap Gesture in viewDidLoad and then hide keyboard

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    [_tableView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
- (void)hideKeyboard
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Or on github you certainly found a library that hide your keyboard