# Dismiss Keyboard On drag

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, search, keyboard

I would like to dismiss the keyboard on swipe/drag after i search for results in my `searchController`.

I tried doing it through the `main.storyboard` but it didn't help.

if i search and get many results i would like scroll down and then the keyboard will `dismiss` and let me see my results better.If anyone can help that would be great, Thanks ahead !

Right now, When i have my results as seen in the picture the keyboard stays when i scroll down and its kind of annoying.

I am using Swift 2.3 and Xcode 8.1

[image]

Here is my searchController setup just in case :

```
// MARK : Search ! //

    var searchController : UISearchController!

    var resultsController = UITableViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        definesPresentationContext = true
        self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
        self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "חפש ברים"
        self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        ////// MARK: END Of Search //////
}
```

## **Edit:pkc456 Has Solved it.Works,but has a tiny issue**

The last result's Cell is being cut in half! :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement the [scroll view delegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate) method (`scrollViewWillBeginDragging`). In this method `resignFirstResponder` your search bar. You can also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4399893/988169) SO answer.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()//self.searchBar?.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Comment: Can you help me with physical Code maybe? sorry i just started coding and have no idea what so ever what to do  xD

Comment: I am using a tableViewController so the delegate in the class row is redundant right?

Comment: Write this in your case:- `class ViewController: UITableViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate ` . Just implement the UIScrollviewDelegate.

Comment: i get an error its redundant to add this protocol. + the func doesn't work and it didn't solve my problem :\

Comment: Just remove this line and implement the method(`scrollViewWillBeginDragging `) only.

Comment: Tried it . Did not work for me , I get This error :  `Value of type 'MyViewController' has no member 'searchBar'` . So i tried replacing the `searchBar` with `searchController` & `resultsController` and it did not work either.

Comment: try `searchController.searchBar`

Comment: That worked! finally ! Thanks a lot for the effort .

Comment: I see something weird here tho , the last result's Cell is being cut in half i will add a picture just a sec

Comment: The last cell's size issue is related to auto layout. Describe the issue in a separate question.

Comment: damn , need to wait like an hour cause i asked about this not so long ago :)

Comment: it happens only in my searchController and not regular tableView ... is it still about Auto layout?

Comment: i made a question about it can you take a look please ?

Answer (score 15):

Easy way to dismiss keyboard when touch or drag (applicable to TableView, CollectionView, ScrollView)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As you are using a tableview u can able to dismiss keyboard while dragging using this property .

Swift

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.onDrag
```

Objective C

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode =  UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag
```

Comment: not working ... as said tried already applying this to the `tableView` within the `main.storyboard` , need to apply it to the UISearchController?

Comment: need to be changed to : UIScrollView.KeyboardDismissMode.onDrag

Answer (score 1):

tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag

Answer (score 0):

- Use tap gesture to dismiss the keyboard. Try the solution as given below:

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:      Selector("hideKeyboard"))
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
  }

  func hideKeyboard() {
    tableView.endEditing(true)
  }
  ```

Comment: The user said "swipe/drag" not "tap," but regardless, you need to do this:
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.hideKeyboard))
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

Answer (score 0):

**You add this UIScrollViewDelegate**

**// MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate**

```
  func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        if(velocity.y < 0){
//Scroll down 
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you using swift 3.0 or swift 2?

Comment: it did tell me to remove the `_ `but thats all really .